# alongside of vs. alongside

Tags: prepositional-phrases, ellipsis

*Fascism has opened up the depths of society for politics. Today, not only in peasant homes but also in city skyscrapers, there lives **alongside of** the twentieth century the tenth or thirteenth.*

Could the preposition *of* can be omitted in the above sentence without a change of the meaning?

Answer (score 5):

It is much more natural without *of*. Of the 8,339 citation for *alongside* in the Corpus of Contemporary English, only 126 are for *alongside of*.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that in many contexts, ***alongside*** can be directly replaced by ***beside***. But whereas *alongside **of*** is normally at least "acceptable" (albeit also "unnecessary") to many native speakers in many contexts, I don't think ***beside of*** could ever work.